# Struggle for Catan card sizes

Tags: card-sleeves, struggle-for-catan

Hi I'm looking to buy card sleeves as a surprise for a friend who has Struggle for Catan but can't seem to find the cards' dimensions. Please help.

Comment: Is this for the US or EU game? Mayfair and 999 Games use different card sizes.

Comment: It's the US version

Comment: FYI: some of the cards are double sided and are flipped throughout the game, so clear card sleeves may be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post on boardgamegeek.com](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/164572/item/2968811#item2968811):

> SwanPanasia 'Standard USA' 57x90mm sleeves are reported to fit these cards perfectly. They are, however, larger than similarly-sized sleeves from other makers, so those other makers 'Standard USA' sleeves may or may not fit these cards.

Those card sleeves can be found for sale on [SwanPanasia's site](https://www.swanpanasiasleeves.com/). [Standard](https://www.swanpanasiasleeves.com/collections/standard-sleeves/products/swan-card-sleeves-57x90-mm-std-usa-160-per-pack) or [Premium](https://www.swanpanasiasleeves.com/collections/premium-sleeves/products/swan-prem-card-sleeves-57x90-mm-std-usa-100-per-pack).

Answer (score 0):

These fit perfectly, I bought them for a close friend who I play Catan with and he liked them so much he bought a whole bunch more.  They only fit the US regular size version not the hand painted wood version with small cards.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00A28RG5C?ref_=pe_623860_70668690](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A28RG5C)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah we found Joe's suggestef card size fits US version perfectly. Good to know you can order via amazon.